# phone makes touch vibration sounds when on facebook

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Why my galaxy s3 make a vibration sound like im recieving a notification while I'm on facebook. While this is happening I am not touching my phone, its happening while I am reading something on facebook or a website. Again, I am not touching the screen in any way, just holding my phone while reading something on facebook or a website.

Comment: Is there a question here? Could you please rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds silly, but I think it is likely that your hand is wrapped around the phone and thereby gently touching the screen with the tip of your fingers OR you are touching the volume down key that goes to vibrate mode.

Technical possibilities could be:

-Setting in the Facebook app, maybe it is sending some sort of notification equivalent that just vibrates instead of showing up on your screen.

-It could also be a different application that runs in the background and gives you notification vibrations. To solve that, go to applications manager, and click through applications and disable push notifications until you find the culprit.

Hope that helped.